# Binding IsEnabled to a property of a custom type collection and refresh trigger

Tags: wpf, binding, model-binding

I have a window with a listbox containing several items. There is a itemtemplate which defines they should be represented by a checkbox:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Converters"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Path=Item.Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Grid.Row="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Margin="5"
                Content="Test"
                IsEnabled="{Binding Customers, Converter={converters:CustomersToBoolConverter}}"
                />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Next, I declare the binded 'Customers' collection and its items in the code behind like so:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window,  INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Customer>> Customers { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Customers = new ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Customer>>();
        Customers.Add(new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { Name = "Kelly Smith" }));
        Customers.Add(new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { Name = "Joe Brown" }));
        Customers.Add(new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { Name = "Herb Dean" }));
        Customers.Add(new CheckedListItem<Customer>(new Customer() { Name = "John Paul" }));

        DataContext = this;
    }

     void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Customers"));

    }
}
```

Here is the Customer class definition:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the definition  of the CheckedListItem class:

```
public class CheckedListItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool isChecked;
    private T item;

    public CheckedListItem()
    { }

    public CheckedListItem(T item, bool isChecked = false)
    {
        this.item = item;
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }

    public T Item
    {
        get { return item; }
        set
        {
            item = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item"));
        }
    }


    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;                
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
        }
    }
```

This latter implements my INPC logic.

I bind the status of my button to the Customers list and the output of a converter which returns true if any of the items is checked.

it works well when loading the window, however, if I check any item of the list, nothing happens. Moreover, if I implement the INPC logic in the class MainWindow and explicitly call

```
if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Customers"));
```

Then, the notification is sent to my window and the status of the button is refreshed just fine.

My question is how can I send this notification from within the CheckedListItem, is it possible?

Code source : http://www.jarloo.com/how-to-create-a-checkedlistbox-in-wpf/

Comment: Maybe `Customers.CollectionChanged += (s,e)=> OnPropertyChanged("Customers")`?

Comment: Binding in WPF is special way to BIND to some objects, and if you want to use it, only one thing that you need to do - is to implement INPC interface and tell wpf when to update properties. This is simple when you are using MVVM pattern, where your ViewModel - is a simple INPC object to which you can bind to. P.S. sorry for my eng.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to `CollectionChanged` event of `ObservableCollection` which Occurs when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed.

You can put the event subscription code in MainWindow Constructor

```
Customers.CollectionChanged += Customers_CollectionChanged;
```

And handler in code behind :

```
void Customers_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            /// Your code
        }
```